# XPath to get text by sibling HTML element

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath

I have having trouble getting my specific string from an ordered list.  I am using C# and Visual Studio to search a website for a specific string to then import into an Excel sheet.  Specifically, this value needs to be a birthdate.  My current request for the string is as follows:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[contains(text(), 'Birthdate')]")).Text;
```

The Ordered list that I am searching through is as follows:

```
<ol>                  
  <li>
        <label>Name</label>Humphries, Ryan</li>
    <li>
        <label>Birthdate</label>11/14/1992</li>
    <li>
        <label>SSN</label>
```

I can search for 'Birthdate' and I get that string to return to my document with my current code, however, I want the actual birthdate, not the label.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, you *cannot find/refer to a text node with selenium directly*. The common way to approach this problem is to get the text of the parent element and "subtract" the child element's text from it.

In other words, find the `li` element, get the text and replace `Birthdate` with an empty string:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//li[label = 'Birthdate']")).Text.Replace("Birthdate", "")
```

Comment: Thank you for such a quick response!  Specifically, my code is as follows:


    `activesheet.Range["B" + n].Value = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//li[label = 'Birthdate]")).Text.Replace("Birthdate", "");` 



Your solution does help me, but the area in my Excel sheet remains blank.  I am just a bit puzzled as to why.  Any suggestions?  Thank you! I apologize for formatting, I am new to the site.

Comment: @Rinktacular thank you, can you print out the result of `driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//li[label = 'Birthdate]")).Text.Replace("Birthdate", "")` on the console and see what the value is going to be?

Comment: @alecxe I created a new variable, String DOB, with messagebox() outputting a blank window when I tell it to show me DOB, So, I am under the assumption that is is blank and/or null.

`DOB = activesheet.Range["B" + n].Value = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//li[label = 'Birthdate']")).Text.Replace("Birthdate", "");`

Comment: Side note: changing HTML may be better solution as it would allow easier styling of the text in addition to simplifying the search: `<li><label>Birthdate</label><span class="date">11/14/1992</span></li>`.

Comment: @Rinktacular good, though I think we are on the right track. There can be multiple reasons for that empty string you are getting. Can you give me the link to the target website if it is public? Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe Unfortunately, I am not allowed to share this website.  I am not the one developing it and it is a medical website that would violate many HIPPA violations sharing it elsewhere, I know this makes it much more difficult for you/us, so I apologize for that.

Comment: @alecxe Additionally, I am under the assumption that the field is left blank because we are telling "birthdate" to be replaced with " ", which would leave the field empty.  Again, I thank you for all the help you have given me thus far!